# multiplicating 2 vectors in lisp

Tags: lisp

I'm trying to multiplicate two vectors in lisp.
My code is:

```
(defun produs(x y)
  (cond
    ((or (null x) (null y))
     nil)
    ((eq (cdr x) nil)
     (cons (* (car x) (car y))
           (cdr y))) 
    ((eq (cdr y) nil)
     (cons (* (car x) (car y))
           (cdr x)))
    (t
     (cons (* (car x) (car y))
           (produs (cdr x) (cdr y))))))
```

When I verify

```
(produs '(7) '(1 2))
```

it gives me (7 2).

The 4rd line of code doesn't specify that if the rest of the body of x is nil, then to multiplicate it with all elements of y?

Comment: what kind of vector multiplication are you trying to perform?

Comment: I think you can try to change (cdr y) to (produs (cdr y) x)

Comment: Please indent and format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you want to achieve this code should work:

```
(defun produs(x y)
(cond
((or (null x) (null y)) nil)
((eq (cdr x) nil) ( cons (* (car x)(car y))(produs (cdr y) x )))
((eq (cdr y) nil) ( cons (* (car x)(car y)) (produs (cdr x) y)))
(t (cons (*(car x)(car y)) (produs (cdr x)(cdr y))))
)
)
```

The problem was that you were not "saying" to multiplicate all elements  with the head x, but just adding all remaining elements in y to your result list.

```
(produs '(7) '(1 2)) => (7 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to refactor the code a little to avoid repeating yourself:

```
(defun produs (x y)
  (when (and x y)
    (cons (* (first x) (first y))
          (let ((rx (rest x))
                (ry (rest y)))
            (cond
              ((and rx ry) (produs rx ry))
              (rx (produs rx y))
              (ry (produs ry x)))))))
```